# How to create VAO for multiple objects

Tags: opengl

I am drawing two triangles using two different VAO.

This is the data set for the triangles.

```
float TriangleRight[] = {
        // positions                          // Tex Coords    // Normals
         0.0f , 0.0f , 0.0f ,                 0.0f,0.0,             1.0,   0.0,0.0,
         xWidth  ,  yHeight , 0.0f,    0.0f,0.0,              1.0 , 0.0,0.0,
         xWidth  , -yHeight ,0.0f,    0.0f,0.0,              1.0 , 0.0,0.0
    };  


float TriangleLeft[] = {
        // positions      
         0.0f , 0.0f , 0.0f ,                0.0f,0.0,              1.0,   0.0,0.0,
         -xWidth ,  yHeight ,0.0f,    0.0f,0.0,               1.0 , 0.0,0.0,
        -xWidth , -yHeight ,0.0f,     0.0f,0.0,                1.0 , 0.0,0.0,
    };
```

I define two different VAO objects along with VBO and call both of them for drawing.

```
glBindVertexArray(m_VAOTriangleRight);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
glBindVertexArray(0);


 glBindVertexArray(m_VAOTriangleLeft);
 glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
 glBindVertexArray(0);
```

How can I configure my data so that I can do this in just one VAO object.

This is the rendered output.

[image]

Comment: Put `TriangleRight` and `TriangleLeft` in 1 buffer and call `glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);`

Comment: @Rabbid76 Thank you for the answer , is there a performance hit if we use multiple VAO objects instead of one for drawing ?

Comment: As a rule of thumb, try to avoid tiny buffer objects and try to minimize the number of OpenGL instructions that are executed in each frame.